# Saving two fig that can be superposed_ Matlab

Tags: matlab, position, size, figure

I am saving two matlab figures as png and I want them to have the same size in order to be perfectly superposable.

The first figure is computed by the function 'FilledCircle2' which is a circle divided in half with two colors.
The second figure is computed by function 'FilledCircleL' which is the left half of the circle computed by the function 'FilledCircle2'.

I want to be able to have two figures, both with the same size so they can be perfectly superposed.
Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code, with both of the functions and respective outputs:

```
function []=FilledCircle2(x0,y0,Radius,N, col1, col2)
if(N<=1)
    error('N must be greater than 1');
end
hold on
axis equal
axis off
hold on 

t=(0:N)*2*pi/N; %t=-pi:0.01:pi
x=Radius*cos(t)+x0;
y=Radius*sin(t)+y0;
plot(x,y)
hold on 

%Divide circle in to 2 equal parts
n=2;
thetas = linspace(-pi, pi,n+1); %linspace generates n points. The space between the points is [(pi/2)-(-pi/2)]/(n)

% Specify any colors wanted
colors = [col1; col2];

for k = 1:n
    tt = linspace(thetas(k), thetas(k+1));
    xi = Radius * cos(tt) + x0;
    yi = Radius * sin(tt) + y0;
    c2= fill([xi(:); x0], [yi(:); y0], colors(k,:)); %Assign diffrent colors to each circle 'slice'

    set (c2, 'edgecolor','white')
    set(c2,'LineWidth',2.0)

    set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperSize',[0.8666,0.8666],'PaperPosition',[0 0 0.8666 0.8666])%setting size (130/150, 130/150, 150pixels per inch being the default size of img), paper position is imporrtant as otherwise i will have extra border
    set(gca, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);
    set(gcf,'color',[0.49019607843137 0.49019607843137 0.49019607843137])%figure properties, rgb(125/255,125/255,125/255)
    fig = gcf;
    fig.InvertHardcopy = 'off'; %saves the fig with the set background color 

    %rotates the plot
    az= 90; %azimuth, az, is the horizontal rotation about the z axis as measured in degrees from the negative y-axis. Positive values indicate counterclockwise rotation 
    el= 90; % vertical elevation of the view point in degrees
    view(az,el);
    hold on
end
```

Here is the output of the function `FilledCircle2(0,0,10,300, 'y', 'r')`:

[[image: Output of function FilledCircle2(0,0,10,300, 'y', 'r')[1]]

```
function []=HalfFilledCircleL(x0,y0,Radius,N, col1)

if(N<=1)
    error('N must be greater than 1');
end

hold on
axis equal
% axis tight
axis off
hold on 

t=(0:N)*(-pi)/N; %t=-pi:0.01:pi
x=Radius*cos(t)+x0;
y=Radius*sin(t)+y0;


hold on

c1=fill(x,y,col1); %filling the semi-circle
set (c1, 'edgecolor','white') %setting the outline color of the semi-circle
set(gcf,'color',[0.49019607843137 0.49019607843137 0.49019607843137])%figure properties, rgb(125/255,125/255,125/255)
set(c1,'LineWidth',2.0)
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperSize',[0.8666,0.8666],'PaperPosition',[0 0 0.8666,0.8666])%setting size (130/150, 130/150, 150pixels per inch being the default size of img), paper position is imporrtant as otherwise i will have extra border
set(gca, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);
fig = gcf;
fig.InvertHardcopy = 'off'; %saves the fig with the set background color 


% %rotates the plot
az= 90; %azimuth, az, is the horizontal rotation about the z axis as measured in degrees from the negative y-axis. Positive values indicate counterclockwise rotation 
el= 90; % vertical elevation of the view point in degrees
view(az,el);

end
```

Here is the output of the function `HalfFilledCircleL(0,0,10,300, 'r')`:

[image: Output of function HalfFilledCircleL(0,0,10,300, 'r')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `xlim` and `ylim` to set the xy limits of the axes:

```
figure;
HalfFilledCircleL(0,0,10,300, 'r');
xlim([-12 12]);ylim([-12 12]);
az= -90; %azimuth, az, is the horizontal rotation about the z axis as measured in degrees from the negative y-axis. Positive values indicate counterclockwise rotation 
el= 90; % vertical elevation of the view point in degrees
view(az,el);

figure;
FilledCircle2(0,0,10,300, 'y', 'r');
xlim([-12 12]);ylim([-12 12]);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @user2999345 !